# Django Queryset counting

Tags: python, django-queryset

I have following model fields

```
    class Program(models.Model):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
          course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
          ...
```

this model can have programs like "Computer Science", "Engineering", "Accountancy"
I would like my list have number that count like

```
          |  name                           | course
----------|---------------------------------|--------------------------
    1     |    Bar                          | Computer Science
----------|---------------------------------|--------------------------
    2     |    Foo                          | Computer Science
----------|---------------------------------|--------------------------

----------|---------------------------------|--------------------------
    1     |    Bar1                         | Engineering
----------|---------------------------------|--------------------------
```

and so on, I tried initializing and add count += 1 in forloop however it keeps on counting 1, 2,3... I don't want that output.

Comment: so you want to count entries by course, is it?

Comment: yes,  and when the course were different the number should be back at 1

Answer (score 0):

No need for the having a loop, Django Model keeps the account of the count

Get the count by this code -

```
program=Program.objects.count()
```

Comment: using this will count 1 to the nth values, which is not what I need. I just want to count per course say, if I have name that has course of CS and that course has 5 entry then the no will be 1,2,3,4,5, then say I have 3 accounting entry then 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out how to do it

```
   program = ""
   count = 0
   for course in Program.objects.order_by('course'):
       if program != course.name:
          program = course.name
          count = 1
       elif program == course.name:
          count += 1
       print(count, course.name)
```

printing the code above is what I expected,

```
1 CS
2 CS
3 CS
-------
1 BSA
2 BSA
3 BSA
-------
1 Educ
2 Educ
3 Educ
4 Educ
```